# How to print only name in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
listofallvms =
[
    [
        {
            "Name": "aaa"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Name": "bbb"
        }
    ],
]
```

From the above data, I want to display only data of Name as follows:

```
aaa
bbb
```

How to do that any idea?

Currently, I am using below code.

```
for i in "${listofallvms[0]}"; 
do 
   echo $i | jq .[].[] 
done
```

Comment: It's not clear what the array `listofallvms` contains. The JSON structure you show does not map straightforwardly to a Bash array.

Comment: If it's really JSON, it should be easy to extract with `jq -r`

Comment: `grep -Po '(?<=Name": ").*(?=")' file.txt`

Comment: Is it a json file? Kindly confirm once. Also confirm if you can use `jq` tool for this one?

Comment: Actually, listofallvms is a variable that stores all my data. I am not using any external file @Jetchisel

Comment: @DhananjayGahiwade, Seeing your profile came to know you never accepted any answer of questions Give it sometime when few answers are there, check them and reply back to users how it went. For gratitude you could up-vote all helpful answers(to encourage users on SO) and could accept an answer out of them all. you could see this link [What one could do when someone gets helpful answer on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) cheers and happy learning. Now also you could go to your OLD answers, could accept answer wherever it applicable.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `jq` code. Where `listofallvms` is your shell variable which is being passed to `jq` command as an input. Also your variable was having extra comma which was breaking json format so I had fixed it below.

```bash
##Shell variable here.
listofallvms='[
    [
        {
            "Name": "aaa"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Name": "bbb"
        }
    ]
]'
```

`jq` code here: Using `jq` with its `-r` option to get output in raw format.

```
jq -r '.[][].Name' <<<"$listofallvms"
```

Comment: @DhananjayGahiwade, could you please do let me know if this has worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this like that in your case

```
grep Name yourfile | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d "\"" -f 2
```

And the output is

```
aaa
bbb
```

Try this.